# Hide dock bar permanently

Tags: dock

Is it possible to hide dock bar permanently? I know we can make dock bar hide/appear automatically. But I don't want dock bar to appear even when the arrow moves on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try hiding it and then setting a long delay before it appears.
Something like:
`defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 10000 && killall Dock`